# Matlab: subtract rows in a single matrix consecutively by iterative method

Tags: arrays, matlab, iteration, operation

Let us assume there is a matrix [mXn]. for example: a=[2 9; 5 7; 8 25; 1 6; 3 9].

I would like to know how  to subtract 1st row from 2nd row and so on till end where the difference between two row is 1.

Next subtract first row from 3rd row and so on where the difference is 2.

And after each loop save the output of the new matrix with a name respective to the loop say for difference1 name may be as newMatDif_1 and so one.

```
diff1----5-2 7-9; 8-2 25-9; .......newMatDiff_1  
diff2----8-2 25-9; 3-8  9-25;.......newMatDiff_2    
diff3----1-2 6-9; .......newMatDiff_3
```

Comment: shouldn't the first one be: `5-2 7-9; 8-5 25-7; 1-8 6-25; 3-1 9-6; ...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your naming scheme is not really feasible or useful in MATLAB, so I've used a 3-dimensional array to hold the differences. The key to this operation is rotating the rows of the array, for which I've defined a function:

```
rotate_rows = @(A, n) ( [ A((n+1):end,:); A(1:n,:)]);

for r = 1:rows(A)-1
    diffs(:,:,r) = a - rotate_rows(a,r);
end
```

Comment: Actually what you have done is what i do not want. Let me clarify the problem in details. 
a.) I have a Matrix of 5X2. 
b.) Now I would like to subtract R1-R2, R2-R3,.....
c.) I would also like to subtract R1-R3, R2-R4,.......
d.) Similarly R1-R4, R2-R5,....
here if you look then the ith number of rows from which I am subtracting is increasing.

Also for each loop of (any for, while, do....) is there any possible way to get the answers saved in a file automatic named for the respective loop?

Comment: Try running the code. You'll find that every subtraction you are looking for is indeed computed and stored, plus a few more that don't really get in the way but allow for simpler code. It is impossible in MATLAB for a loop to create new variable names or to increment a variable name. You could save each matrix to a separate .mat file, but within that .mat file they would still have the same variable name, so you wouldn't be able to load more than one without the new .mat file overwriting the contents of the same workspace variable. Is that really what you want?